# How to read data from a 6DOF sensor by SPI?

Tags: sensor, spi, communication

I am new to firmware programing.

I have a [6 DOF sensor](https://product.tdk.com/system/files/dam/doc/product/sensor/mortion-inertial/imu/data_sheet/ds-000451-icm-42670-p.pdf) module and want to connect to a [ESP12F development board](https://docs.ai-thinker.com/_media/esp8266/boards/nodemcu-8266_v1.2_ch340%E4%B8%B2%E5%8F%A3%E8%8A%AF%E7%89%87_%E5%BC%80%E5%8F%91%E6%9D%BF%E5%8E%9F%E7%90%86%E5%9B%BE.pdf) to read data. Please see below picture for my 6 DOF sensor module.

[image]

Here are my current connections:

```
3V3  -> 3V3,
GND  -> GND,
MISO -> PIN8,
MOSI -> PIN7,
CLK  -> PIN9,
CS   -> PIN11
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>

#define csPin 15

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.printf("HELLO WORLD");
  SPI.begin();
  pinMode(csPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(csPin, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.printf(".");
  delay(3000);
  digitalWrite(csPin, LOW);
  byte command = 0x00; 
  SPI.transfer(command);
  byte data = SPI.transfer(0x00);

  digitalWrite(csPin, HIGH);

  Serial.print("Received data: ");
  Serial.println(data); // output: 0 or 255
}
```

Does the output as 0 or 255 indicate error? How can I read the data from sensor by SPI?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How does your `CS   -> PIN11` connection correlate with your `#define csPin 15` code?